# SCIM De-Activate User: Invalid date for Terminate_Date__c

Tags: rest-api, salesforcesdk, disable

I'm trying to deactivate a user by calling the below salesforce API

PUT /services/scim/v1/Users/{uid}

{

"userName":"abc@example.com",
  "externalId":"abc@example.com",
  "title":"RSM",
  "active":false,
  "name":{

```
"familyName":"John",
"givenName":"Smith"
```

},
  "emails": [   {
      "type": "work",
      "primary": true,
      "value": "abc@example.com"
   }],
   "addresses": [
    {
      "streetAddress": "100 ABC Plaza",
      "region": "CA",
      "postalCode": "91608",
      "country": "USA"
    }
  ],
   "entitlements":    [
            {
         "value": "00e70000000zomIBCQ",
         "primary": true
      }
    ],
    "roles":    [
            {
         "value": "00E700000015ObpBAB"
      }
    ],
    "urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0":    {
      "employeeNumber": "12345",
      "department": "Sales",
      "division":"Sales Division",
      "manager":{
        "managerId":"005700000021d9OAB1"
      }
      },
    "urn:salesforce:schemas:extension:00DS0000003L0j0MAC":    {
        "Terminate_Date__c":"2018-01-09T07:44:35Z"
   }

}

I get the below error

{"Errors": [{
   "description": "Invalid date: 2018-01-09T07:44:35Z",
   "code": 409
}]}

What is the format I'm supposed to use for Terminate_Date__c?

Thanks!